# How to Setup FTP to use in locally hosted wordpress

Tags: login, ftp, wordpress

I have installed wordpress on my ubuntu 10.10 desktop edition and I am trying to install plugin from the browser (I know I can drop it to the wp-content/plugin but I want to do it via the web browser using FTP) I get  this screen when I am trying to set auto update or install a plugin from web browser.

[image]

I provide the hostname 127.0.0.1
and Username and password the ones that I use to login to wordpress. I get the error

> Username/password Incorrect and cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:20

I think i'll have to grant a user with ftp password but I dont know how.
I have already installed vsftp but when I try "ftp 127.0.0.1" I get -

```
$ ftp 127.0.0.1
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.0)
Name (127.0.0.1:gaurav): root
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
ftp>
```

Wordpress is running locally on my Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well your Wordpress login and your FTP login are two different things. I have see that you use vsFTPd, so one easy thing that you can do it this :

Edit the vsFTPd configuration file :

```
gksu gedit /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Add this at the end :

```
local_enable=YES
```

Restart your vsFTPd server :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Now you should be able to connect to your FTP using your Ubuntu login.

Comment: and how can I grant a user (wordpress user) access to FTP who can use FTP over the network

Comment: I would also not login as root, but create a dummy user, make him part of your www-data group and use it to push updates/install

Comment: I had this same issue and just wanted to add for any others that are going through this that you need to use '127.0.0.1' and not 'localhost'. Or at least I did. Also had to use FTP not FTPS.

Comment: -1 Even though it's listed as best answer, it lacks the information that write_enable is commented out by default. If you do not uncomment, your solution still doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

Just add this line to wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Then It will be OK.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages with this method? 
Seems like the best/easiest one to me but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

For me changing the ownership of the wordpress folder solved the issue.

```
sudo chown -R www-data wordpress
```

Comment: This worked right away for me!

Comment: It doesn't help here :/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the default file the problem I had was not seeing enable write access.  That resolved my problems.

```
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Comment: The same issue here, write_enable is commented out by default. Thanks for the tip.
It's nowhere mentioned here, but I also changed the home directory for the wordpress ftp user to /var/www/html (or whatever the path to the site is). I'm not sure if this is actually needed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

When I created my Ubuntu server I installed a wordpress site and everytime I wanted to update a plugin I needed ftp access which was really annoying. I knew I could just add the ftp details in the config for wordpress but I was Like NAH!
So It turned out that wordpress can't write files to the wp-content directory because apache doesn't have permission to edit the directory so this is how I fixed it.

Copy group file to groups in the same directory

```
sudo cp /etc/group /etc/groups
```

Then give Recursive Permission to apache

```
sudo chown -R www-data:root /var/www
```

Thats it.

Another way of doing it is by editing apache envvars

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Edit the lines where it says

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

And replace www-data with your username for ubuntu

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=USERNAME
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=USERNAME
```

now restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and then make sure your account has permissions to the directory

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME:USERNAME /var/www
```

If this doesnt work for you then simply reply.

Answer (score 1):

To configure `vsftpd`, open `vsftpd.conf` in `/etc` and 
copy paste the following into your vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/srv/ftp
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to my FTP server.
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Note:
You should create a new directory inside `/srv` in the name ftp or what ever name you prefer.If you prefer another name then you should change the line `anon_root=/srv/ftp` to  `anon_root=/srv/toyourfoldername` Now place all your files inside the folder **/srv/ftp**

To test your settings in localhost type:

`ftp://127.0.0.1`
If you have any problems let me know.

To start/stop/restart vsftpd:

```
sudo service vsftpd start
sudo service vsftpd stop
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: +1 for `sudo service vsftpd ....`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Add this file to `wp-config.php`:

```php
if(is_admin()) {
    add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
    define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
}
```

for more http://www.jamison.org/2010/12/04/how-to-configure-wordpress-for-automatic-ftps-updates-using-vsftp-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and here how I resolved it.

1) You have to check what group owned that specific wordpress folder. i.e www-data. Then make sure the group owned recursively. You can can do

`sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/wordpress`

2) the ftpuser that you plan to use need to belong to www-data group. You can  check by following.

`groups ftpuser`

If it is not in that group, just add it. here how i did it.

`sudo usermod -a -G www-data ftpuser`

The last thing is to set the default folder of the ftpuser to your wordpress folder.

```
usermod -d /var/www/wordpress ftpuser
```

that's it...