# Installing FTP and adding user to FTP account

Tags: 13.04, server, ftp, adduser

I installed ftp on a ubuntu server and now want to add a user. I am using this tutorial : http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/383

Everything was working fine but I stuck on the step of adding user. when I did this :

```
# sudo pure-pw useradd remo -u ftpuser -g ftpgroup -d /home/pubftp/remo -N 10
```

It gives me error "You must give nonroot uid and gid".

I thought to chek the uid and gid of the user and put it in command but the user is not created yet. so can't get its uid.

How to do it friends?

Answer (score 1):

Don't Need to Use the above command , If You using a Local User , then Create a Account just using `useradd usernamehere` , and Create a Password for user too, Then Change the configuration file to `local_user YES` , Connect from the Client to check and it will Work , You local User files will Stored Under `/home/username` , The local user Will be Redirect to the home directory of local user , If you Create a Anonymous FTP login its will Redirect to `/var/ftp/pub` that's the different , If you Don't Need to Browse all Folder except the home Directory Enable `Chroot_local_enable YES` , Then Your Local User can access Only His Home Directory

Comment: I am transferring my wordpress site. I want to transfer wordpress files using this FTP account and put it into the correct directory.

Comment: Use the command useradd -d /username/var/ftp/directoryname

Comment: Hope this will help for little idea http://askubuntu.com/questions/14371/how-to-setup-ftp-to-use-in-locally-hosted-wordpress